# I need to catch many blocks as function parameters, ruby can do that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have this input in order to get the status name (status) and the status ({unassigned: 0, assigned: 1, resolved: 2, closed: 3}) and the blocks
(event :assign do
transition :unassigned => :assigned
end)

```
#   enum status: {unassigned: 0, assigned: 1, resolved: 2, closed: 3} do
#     event :assign do
#       transition :unassigned => :assigned
#     end
#   end
```

i was trying to implement but i dont have idea to do get those parameters:

```
class State
    def initialize()       
    end

    def self.handler(enum_name, **status, &blocks)
        p 'enum_name', enum_name
    end    
end 

State.handler status: {unassigned: 0, assigned: 1, resolved: 2, closed: 3} do
    #     event :assign do
    #       transition :unassigned => :assigned
    #     end
    #   end
```

pretty much i am trying to implement this code by my self on mode to learn ruby https://github.com/amatsuda/stateful_enum/blob/master/lib/stateful_enum/active_record_extension.rb

by the answer from @BroiSatse

i tested like this and not working

```
outer(:hello) do
    self.class #=> MyBuilder
    data = { unassigned: 0 } do
                event :assign do
                    transition :unassigned => :assigned
                end
            end 
    inner(:one) {  data  }
    @values[:one][:@something]
    
    #inner(:two) { :twotwo }
    #p "worked", @values[:two][:@something]
  end
```

i am getting this error:

my_builder.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected `do', expecting` end'
data = { unassigned: 0 } do
my_builder.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby methods accept only one block and there's no way around this. However, what you're seeing in your examples is not a single method with multiple blocks - it's a single method, single block. But that block invokes another method which takes another block.

To build sth similar, you need to define an object that will respond to inner methods and then wrap it neatly in the outer method:

```
class MyBuilder
  attr_reader :values

  def initialize(something)
    @something = something
    @values = {}
  end

  def inner(name, &block)
    @values[name] = block
  end
end

def outer(sth, &block)
  builder = MyBuilder.new(sth)
  builder.instance_exec(&block) # This is the moment you actually run the block
  # do sth more interesting with collected configuration
  builder.values
end

outer(:hello) do
  self.class #=> MyBuilder

  inner(:one) { :oneone }
  inner(:two) { :twotwo }
end

#=> { one: #Proc, two: #Proc }
```

This is naturally just a very simplified boilerplate of how this type of syntax is achieved. The key point is `instance_exec` method which evaluates the given block **and sets the `self` inside the block to given object**. And any unrecognized token in the block is automatically treated as method invocation on self.

Note, that there are two quite similar methods for that `instance_exec` and `instance_eval` - I usually prefer `instance_exec` as it is a bit more flexible. But please do have a read about the differences between those two.